# In Golang, how can I sort a list of strings alphabetically without completely ignoring case?

Tags: sorting, go, alphabetical-sort

I want the strings to be sorted alphabetically with control over whether "A" comes before "a".

In the Less() function using strings.ToLower() doesn't achieve this. Sometimes "A" comes before "a", and sometimes after.

Comment: Do you want `"A"` to ALWAYS precede `"a"`? Can you give some sample in/out?

Comment: Yes ALWAYS. Eg: A a X x Y y Z z (assume these are all strings). I had expected there to be a standard alphabetical ordering string function, but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 6):

instead of comparing the entire string using `strings.ToLower`, compare the individual runes.

https://play.golang.org/p/RUMlmrb7C3g

```
type ByCase []string

func (s ByCase) Len() int      { return len(s) }
func (s ByCase) Swap(i, j int) { s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] }

func (s ByCase) Less(i, j int) bool {
    iRunes := []rune(s[i])
    jRunes := []rune(s[j])

    max := len(iRunes)
    if max > len(jRunes) {
        max = len(jRunes)
    }

    for idx := 0; idx < max; idx++ {
        ir := iRunes[idx]
        jr := jRunes[idx]

        lir := unicode.ToLower(ir)
        ljr := unicode.ToLower(jr)

        if lir != ljr {
            return lir < ljr
        }

        // the lowercase runes are the same, so compare the original
        if ir != jr {
            return ir < jr
        }
    }

    // If the strings are the same up to the length of the shortest string, 
    // the shorter string comes first
    return len(iRunes) < len(jRunes)
}
```

Comment: This might be more terse if the comparison is `if ir == jr { // compare upper vs lower } else { return lir < jir } `. It makes it look more like a special case and less like totally new logic.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I don't think that quite works (if they're equal, there's nothing to compare). I wanted this to be very explicit for the OP, but I think I like this condensed logic better http://play.golang.org/p/twDrCxdYoi

Comment: Ah yes, I was backwards :)

Answer (score 5):

This may be a solution:

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "sort"
    "fmt"
)

var listOfStrings []string = []string{
    "mars bar",
    "milk-duds",
    "Mars bar",
    "milk",
    "milky-way",
    "Milk",
    "Milky-way",
    "mars",
}

type Alphabetic []string

func (list Alphabetic) Len() int { return len(list) }

func (list Alphabetic) Swap(i, j int) { list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i] }

func (list Alphabetic) Less(i, j int) bool {
    var si string = list[i]
    var sj string = list[j]
    var si_lower = strings.ToLower(si)
    var sj_lower = strings.ToLower(sj)
    if si_lower == sj_lower {
        return si < sj
    }
    return si_lower < sj_lower
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("UNSORTED")
    printStrings(listOfStrings)
    sort.Sort(Alphabetic(listOfStrings))
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("SORTED ALPHABETICALLY")
    printStrings(listOfStrings)
}

func printStrings(slice []string) {
    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        fmt.Println(slice[i])
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
UNSORTED
mars bar
milk-duds
Mars bar
milk
milky-way
Milk
Milky-way
mars

SORTED ALPHABETICALLY
mars
Mars bar
mars bar
Milk
milk
milk-duds
Milky-way
milky-way
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a Unicode friendly method that utilizes `strings.Map`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sort"
   "strings"
   "unicode"
)

type slice struct { sort.StringSlice }

func (s slice) Less(d, e int) bool {
   t := strings.Map(unicode.ToUpper, s.StringSlice[d])
   u := strings.Map(unicode.ToUpper, s.StringSlice[e])
   return t < u
}

func main() {
   a := slice{
      sort.StringSlice{"a", "b", "A", "B"},
   }
   sort.Sort(a)
   fmt.Println(a.StringSlice) // [a A b B]
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Map